# Form updating the data of the last array created and not the one selected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form that when selecting an already existing array and trying to edit it, it shows the correct information. 
But when saving it, it saves all off the information into the last array created and replaces it.

Any one have an idea of what could be causing this?

Controller:

```
/**
 * update job detail in database
 */

public function updateJob(Request $request, $id){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:50',
        'category' => 'required|numeric',
        'last_date' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required|min:20',
        'city' => 'required',
        'vacancies' => 'nullable|numeric',
    ]);

    $job = Posts::find($id);

    $setting = Settings::first();
    $company = Companies::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();

    $job->title             = $request->title;
    $job->description       = $request->description;
    $job->type              = $request->type;
    $job->cat_id            = $request->category;
    $job->experience        = $request->experience;
    $job->city_id           = $request->city;
    $job->total_vacancies   = $request->vacancies;
    $job->job_type_id       = $request->job_type;
    $job->salary            = $request->salary;
    $job->last_date         = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->last_date);                            
    $job->shift             = $request->shift;
    $job->status            = 'active';


    $job->save();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $job-> save();  why there is a space before save()?

Comment: It was by accident, however error still persists after fixing it.
Thank you for noticing.

Comment: can you please check the id you are sending?
$job = Posts::find($id); // looks like your code is right and its replacing the values of job found by given id.

Comment: Check the value of `$id`. Everything is looking fine.

Comment: What do you mean by `it saves all off the information into the last array created`? Also, `$this->validate()` result is not captured. How do you know what it returned?

Comment: @vivek_23 `$this-validate()` returns `void`. If it fails validation it will exit early and send a response with the errors.

Comment: Try using `Posts::findOrFail($id)` so that an error is thrown if the Post is not found

Comment: @MikeHarrison How do you know it would exit?

Comment: In the table _“Posts”_ `$id` would be a column and my primary key set with an auto_increment.

It is finding the `$id` since it displays the correct information about the post, but insists on saving the information in the last entry replacing it, instead of updating the one I chose. 

`Posts::findOrFail($id)` does not return any error.

Comment: Can you post a before/after the model is updated? Show us what is happening to the data? If I understand what you're saying the data will be the same before/after

Comment: You must be passing the last $id then cause the code looks fine.

Comment: @MikeHarrison Absolutely, [I just created a new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137779/when-editing-a-table-it-updates-the-last-entry-in-the-db-instead-of-the-selecte) with a better explanation and some pictures, any help would be greatly appreciated!