# When editing a table, it updates the last entry in the DB instead of the selected one

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table that can have multiple posts, let’s say that I go to [edit any random post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcucM.png).

It shows me with the correct [information about said post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sohi.png), however once I [change the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOCRB.png) and click on my button to save the information and update the post, it [updates the last post that was created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8RPj.png) instead of the chosen one.

`Posts` would be the table with the column `id` as my primary key using an `auto_increment` for identification.

HTML:

```
{{Form::open(['url'=> 'employer/jobs', 'method' => 'POST'])}}
{{csrf_field()}}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<h4>Title *</h4>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Name" required value="{{old('title')}}">
</div>

<div class="employees-button text-center no-padding">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-jobs-post job-employee">Save changes</button>
</div>

{{Form::close()}}
```

Controller:

```
 /**
 * return view for edit current post by id
 */

public function show($id){
    $company = Companies::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
    if(count($company)){

        $jobEdit = Posts::find($id);
        $categories = Categories::where('status','active')->get();
        $cities = Cities::all();
        $job_types = JobTypes::where('status','active')->get();

        return view('employer.edit_job', compact('jobEdit', 'categories', 'cities', 'job_types', 'company')); }
        else{
        return Redirect::to('employer/company/add');
    }
}

 /**
 * update post detail in database
 */

public function updateJob(Request $request, $id){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:50',
        'category' => 'required|numeric',
        'last_date' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required|min:20',
        'city' => 'required',
        'vacancies' => 'nullable|numeric',
    ]);

    $job = Posts::find($id);

    $job->title             = $request->title;
    $job->description       = $request->description;
    $job->type              = $request->type;
    $job->cat_id            = $request->category;
    $job->experience        = $request->experience;
    $job->city_id           = $request->city;
    $job->total_vacancies   = $request->vacancies;
    $job->job_type_id       = $request->job_type;
    $job->salary            = $request->salary;
    $job->last_date         = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->last_date);
    $job->shift             = $request->shift;
    $job->status            = 'active';

    $job->save();

    if($request->add_type == 'option2'){
        Session::flash('job_id', $job->id);
         return redirect()->route('theoption2')->with( 'job', $job );
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Updated.');
    }   
}
```

If changed `Posts::findOrFail($id)` does not display any error.

Any help on why it's always updating the information on the last entry would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show how you have initialized the form that calls the update function.

Comment: Change this: `$job = Posts::find($id);` for this: `$job = Posts::where(['id' => $id])->first();`

Comment: Can you post your eh, `Post` model?

Comment: @AntonyMN I Initialized the form like this: `{{ Form::open(['url'=> ['employer', 'job', $job->id, 'edit'], 'method' => 'POST']) }}`

Comment: @EmmanuelHD Unfortunately it has the same behaviour, it keeps updating the last entry on the database.

Comment: After you modify your code as I told you add this conditional `if ($job == null){$job = New Post;}`, if the sql consult returns null, we create a new instance of de Model, please try this.

Comment: Thank you for the support @EmmanuelHD! The variable `$job` doesn't return null, unfortunately it insist's in [returning the $id](https://i.imgur.com/gQUYbUE.png) of the last entry in the DB, not the one that was chosen.

Comment: Can you publish the result of `dd ($ id);` and `dd ($ job);`? There is something that we haven't seen!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the id you are sending to the post, please where is the id coming from? i would have saved each comment with its id to be saved and return it when posting, if you can post your html or where the id is coming from, that will help check your program

Comment: It is calling `{{ Form::open(['url'=> ['employer', 'job', $job->id, 'edit'], 'method' => 'POST']) }}`, I just updated the post with the html, thank you!

Comment: @EmekaOkafor is correct - the ID you are sending to the `updateJob` function is off. Please inspect the ID that is being sent and confirm it is the same ID as the one you click on. Please show us the HTML of the button href and also the editing form. I think you showed us the form when creating a new `Job`.